# Eclipse programatically check project explorer linked to editors

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is it possible using the eclipse plugin API to programatically check if the project explorer link button (double arrows) is enabled?  This is the button that causes the current editor selection to change the project explorer selection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Projects Explorer is open this should work:

```java
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IViewPart view = page.findView("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.ProjectsView");

if (view instanceof CommonNavigator)
 {
   boolean linkingEnabled = ((CommonNavigator)view).isLinkingEnabled();

   ...
 }
```